# Ruby: how to find to which user belongs payment in has many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

So I have this:

```
User:
 has_many: subscriptions

Subscription:
 belongs_to: user
 has_many: payments

Payment:
 belongs_to: subscription
```

If i have a Payment id, how can I find a User?

Comment: `@user = Payment.find(id).subscription.user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nick mentioned, `Payment.find(id).subscription.user` will work just great. If this is something you'll be doing often, I'd recommend adding a `has_one :through` relationship as well.

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscription
  has_one :user, through: :subscription
end
```

And then you can directly reference `Payment.find(id).user`!

Answer (score 0):

If you declare an indirect association from Payment to User you can get it directly:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :payments, through: :subscriptions
end

clas Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :payments
end

class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscription
  has_one :user, through: :subscription  
end
```

---

```
user = User.joins(:payments).where(payments: { id: [id] }).first
# or
payment = Payment.eager_load(:user).find(id)
user = payment.user
```